# How to redirect index.php to root in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Actually i want to make auto redirect when open

from

```
test.com/login.php
```

to

```
test.com/login/
```

What should i put on my htaccess file.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are literary tons of tutorials about this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd first redirect to pretty-url if the raw request matches:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ /login/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Now, you deal with the rewritten url to internally redirect to correct page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Your rewrite module should be enabled for doing this?